# How do I use printf to format separate strings into one line?

Tags: java, string, printf

I am using a while loop and getting data from a text file and using classes to reference each string.  I don't have any issues getting the values for each string and printing it out.

However, I am confused on how to use `System.out.printf(....)` to put all of the strings I need in one line while using a loop.

For example, let's say the text file was:

> I
>   like
>   to
>   use
>   computers

I want to use a loop to print out the words into one string and I may have different spacing between each word.

The code I have so far:

```
while (!readyOrder.isEmpty()) {
    s = readyOrder.poll();
    System.out.printf(s.getQuantity() + " x " + s.getName()
        + "(" + s.getType() + ")" + "                "
        + s.getPrice() * s.getQuantity());
    System.out.println(" ");
    total = total + s.getPrice() * s.getQuantity();
}
```

And the output should be:

> 1_x_The Shawshank Redemption_______(DVD)________________19.95

The underlined spaces are where the spaces should be and how long they should be.

How can I use printf to do that?

Comment: It would be great if you could add the code you have so far to the question. This way we might be able to help you mure accurately. Thanks!

Comment: Code is updated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the string padding functionality of printf. For example %-30s formats to width of 30 characters, - means left justify.

```
for (Stock s : Arrays.asList(
        new Stock(1, "The Shawshank Redemption", 100, "DVD"), 
        new Stock(2, "Human Centipede", 123, "VHS"),
        new Stock(1, "Sharknado 2", 123, "Blu ray"))) {

    System.out.printf("%2d x %-30s (%-7s) %5.2f\n",
            s.getQuantity(), s.getName(), s.getType(),
            s.getPrice() * s.getQuantity());
}
```

Output

```
1 x The Shawshank Redemption       (DVD    ) 100.00
2 x Human Centipede                (VHS    ) 246.00
1 x Sharknado 2                    (Blu ray) 123.00
```

Comment: It doesn't format the numbers correctly, and when it loops through each line is not the same length (space wise). Is it just a matter of adjusting numbers.

Comment: The lines are not outputting correctly when I use my while loop. The numbers are not all underneath each other, and the same goes for the type